# Sorting a backbone collection alphabetically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection that is pulling in a bunch of template names for people to use and I would like to sort them alphabetically so their easier to find. I am very unsure of how to do this though.

I have my backbone collection

```
this.templates = new Backbone.Collection();
```

and then I'm sorting through the templates to figure out where to add what.

```
var Names = this.model.collection.models.map(function(model){
  return (model.attributes.Name) ? model.attributes.Name : 'Template';
});

Names.forEach(function(name) {
  _this.templates.add(api.collections[(_this.templateType)].where({Name : name, ShowInToolBox : true}));
//adding a bunch of conditionals to add cretin forms to modules that are outside the scope 
}
```

Is it possible to alphabetize these?

I've tried adding `.sortBy("Name")` to the backbone collection, but it just stopped my code from running.

Comment: If these answers have been helpful to you, please mark accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone offers the [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) property for sorting. You can pass the name of the property that the collection should be sorted on into the constructor:

```
this.templates = new Backbone.Collection([], { comparator: 'Name' })
```

Every time the collection changes, it will be re-sorted by the property name in the `comparator.` If you're doing something more complicated, you can define the `comparator` as a function. If you go this route, then I would recommend extending `Backbone.Collection` for clarity:

```
var Templates = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function(template1, template2){
        return template1.get('someValue') - template2.get('someValue')
    }
})

var templates = new Templates()
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone collections can be sorted with the [comparator function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator).

> If you define a comparator, it will be used to maintain the collection in sorted order. This means that as models are added, they are inserted at the correct index in collection.models. A comparator can be defined as a sortBy (pass a function that takes a single argument), as a sort (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments), or as a string indicating the attribute to sort by.